# my phone is not working. How can I get my contacts?

Tags: contacts, data-recovery

My phone is not working. How can I get my contacts from it? I have tried everything to get them. Drying the phone in rice. But the phone still will not work. I need my contacts.

Comment: Have you synced your contacts in any of your accounts?

Comment: first, always remove battery (if possible), and drying is best with open case at 50° degree celsius for ~ 2-3 hours. Depending on google settings, if it is completely dead, just the touch or the screen is dead, or just keys not working, phone model and encryption, there might be a solution to recover the contacts